# How is the Riemann-Siegel formula applied?

Tags: special-functions, riemann-zeta

What is the application of the [Riemann-Siegel formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Siegel_formula):

> $$
>     \zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n^s} + \gamma(1-s)\sum_{n=1}^M\frac{1}{n^{1-s}} + R(s) ,
> $$
>   where $    \displaystyle\gamma(s) = \pi^{1/2-s}\Gamma(s/2)/\Gamma((1-s)/2) $
>   is the factor appearing in the functional equation $\zeta(s) = \gamma(s) \zeta(1 − s)$, and
>   $$
>     R(s) = \frac{-\Gamma(1-s)}{2\pi i}\int \frac{(-x)^{s-1}e^{-Nx}dx}{e^x-1} 
> $$
>   is a contour integral whose contour starts and ends at +∞ and circles the singularities of absolute value at most 2πM.

It is mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/125589/19341), but I don't see its usage. The [Mathworld site](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Riemann-SiegelFormula.html) doesn't help at all:-(

Comment: [This](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1988-0961614-2) and [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-2010-02426-3) have nice discussions...

Comment: See [this](https://circle.ubc.ca/handle/2429/9023) and [this](http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Miscellaneous/zetaevaluations.pdf) as well.

Comment: @J.M. Wow, thanks. This might take me a while, but keep on posting!

Comment: I don't have the time or the mood to write a full discussion, so I left them as comments. Somebody else with more time and motivation might want to do so in the meantime; having said that, all the essential ingredients for implementing Riemann-Siegel in your computing environment of choice are in those papers I linked to.

Comment: What kind of applications are you looking for?

Comment: @Aryabhata Just any. Choose your favorite!

Comment: @draks: Then it is too open ended a question... and is close (IMO) to being a candidate for closure as 'not a real question'.

Comment: @Aryabhata: I had initially guessed "numerically", based on some of OP's previous questions, but as it is currently written, I agree that this one's a bit open-ended...