# fastest way to evaluate $\arg\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\text{t}\right) $

Tags: numerical-methods, special-functions, riemann-zeta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [evaluation of $ \operatorname{Arg}\zeta (1/2+is) $ ??](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125589/evaluation-of-operatornamearg-zeta-1-2is)

If we consider

$$\arg\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2} + i\text{t}\right) = \text{Im }\log\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\text{t}\right)$$

for big values of '$t$' what is the **FASTEST** method (numerical method) to evaluate the Argument of the Riemann zeta function along the critical line?

$$\arg\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\text{t}\right) $$