# Riemann Zeta Function nontrivial zeros on a graph

Tags: riemann-zeta

On a graph, the nontrivial zeros of the zeta function are on the critical strip.  Because the critical strip is vertical, how can any value on the strip be a zero of the zeta function if it isn't directly on the x-axis?  For example, how can one of the zeros, (1/2)+(14.13...)i be a zero if it's above the x-axis?  Thanks!

Comment: Why not? Where is the problem?

Comment: Before one learns about complex numbers, real functions are graphed via the relation $y=f(x)$. With complex numbers, points in the plane are *all* inputs of the function. The domain is the plane, and the codomain is also the plane. If you wanted to graph such a thing, you would need four dimensions (in practice, dimensions can be color, hue, time etc.) | Others: While amusing, I don't think that not knowing about complex numbers deserves a downvote.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447027/orientation-of-zeta-zeroes-on-the-critical-line/447253#447253

Comment: Thanks @Andrew ! :-)

Comment: @RaymondManzoni My pleasure - a great answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The complex plane has two directions, not only the $x$-axis. If $s=x+iy$ is a zero of the Zeta function, this means $0=\zeta(s)=\zeta(x+iy)$, but $y$ need not be zero (and in fact, is not zero for the nontrivial zeros).

Comment: So the complex plane is entirely separate from the real plane?  Could it essentially be said that the values for the complex plane would be the x in a f(x) function, but this time it applies for s in the zeta function?  Pardon my ignorance on the subject, I need to do more researching.

Comment: @Ethan: the complex plane is generated by the real axis ($x$) and the imaginary axis ($iy$) and thus made of complex values $s=x+iy$. What is your real plane ? Is this the graph of a $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ function? Here we are concerned with a function $\zeta$ from $\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ i.e. from a [complex plane](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexPlane.html) to a complex plane. The zeros of $\zeta(s)$ are the points (complex values $s$) from the initial plane that have the image $\zeta(s)=0$ in the destination complex plane.