# More elegant $\zeta(s)$ zeros counting function than $N(T)$

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

The [explicit formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_formulae_(L-function)) expresses the [deep](http://philmat.oxfordjournals.org/content/23/2/233.full.pdf) connection between the [primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number) $p$ and the [non-trivial zeros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis#Riemann_zeta_function) $\rho$ of [$\zeta(s)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function). The [prime-counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Other_prime-counting_functions) is [given by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Formulas_for_prime-counting_functions) the following formula giving primes in terms of $\rho$ (the notation $*$ means that at any point of discontinuity we take the average of the [left and right limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit)):

$$\pi^*(x)=R(x)-\sum_\rho R(x^\rho)-\frac{1}{\ln{x}}+\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan{\frac{\pi}{\ln{x}}}$$

where $R(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n}\operatorname{li}(x^{\frac{1}{n}})$ where $\operatorname{li}(x)$ is the [logarithmic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function). This is complicated, and the [Mobius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function) $\mu(n)$ contains information about primes anyway. However we have an [explicit formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/282848/284973) for the alternative counting function [$\psi^*(x)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function) (counting logarithms of $p$ at prime powers):

$$\psi^*(x)=x-\sum_\rho \frac{x^\rho}{\rho}-\ln{2\pi}-\frac{1}{2}\ln{\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}$$

which is a simpler and more elegant expression for how $p$ depend on $\rho$. I always assumed this would have a companion formula giving a counting function for $\rho$ in terms of $p$, and wondered what it was. [This formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/442686/284973) is not an example since the RHS refers to $\zeta(s)$ and doesn't capture the [Fourier-type duality](http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin/zeta/NTfourier.htm) between $p$ and $\rho$. However I recently came across a formula due to [Guinand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Guinand) (paper [here](http://www.archive.org/stream/proceedingsofthe032881mbp#page/n115/mode/2up); formula also mentioned [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/104570)) for the [counting function](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/533559/284973) [$N(T)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\delta R}\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}\;ds$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/447253/284973) where $R=[-\varepsilon,1+\varepsilon]\times[0,T]$ (i.e. $\left|\{\rho\;|\;\Im(\rho)\in[0,T]\}\right|$; see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle)) assuming the [Riemann hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis):

$$N^*(T)=\frac{T}{2\pi}\ln{\frac{T}{2\pi}}-\frac{T}{2\pi}-{\frac{1}{\pi}\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left[\sum_{n=1}^N \Lambda(n)\frac{\sin{(T\ln{n})}}{\sqrt{n}\ln{n}}-\int_1^N \frac{\sin{(T\ln{t})}}{\sqrt{t}\ln{t}}\;dt-\frac{\sin{(T\ln{N})}}{\ln{N}}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\Lambda(n)}{\sqrt{n}}-2\sqrt{N}\right)\right]}+\frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\arg{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+iT\right)}-T\ln{T}+T\right)+\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan{2T}-\frac{1}{4\pi}\arctan{\sinh{\pi T}}$$

This is what I was looking for since it effectively gives $N(T)$ in terms of the primes. However it is very complicated, making me wonder if there is an alternative way to define a counting function on $\rho$ for which a more [elegant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_beauty) expression in terms of $p$ holds.

**My Question**: Does anyone know of an alternative way to $N(T)$ of counting $\rho$ (analogous to $\psi^*(x)$ for the primes) for which there is a simpler or more elegant expression than that for $N(T)$ in terms of $p$?

Comment: I don't see what you mean. Assuming the RH, the Fourier transform of $h(u) = \frac{\psi(e^u)-e^u-\frac{\ln(1-e^{-2u})}{2}}{e^{u/2}} $ is $\hat{h}(\xi) = \sum_\lambda \delta(\xi-\lambda)$ where $\lambda= Im(\rho)$. This is what says https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_formulae_(L-function)#Weil.27s_explicit_formula by looking at $\langle h,f \rangle =\langle \hat{h},\hat{f} \rangle $ where $f$ is a test function. Of course $h$ is given by the primes, and $N(T) = \langle \hat{h},\hat{f} \rangle $ for some appropriate test function $\hat{f}$.

Comment: And the other way for expressing $N(T)$ is with [the argument principle](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1903742/testing-zeros-of-the-riemann-hypothesis/1903768#1903768)

Comment: @user1952009 I am fully aware that the argument principle can be used (I mentioned that in my question); however, the resulting formula is not the sort of formula I was asking for (being simply the definition of $N(T)$). As to your other point; I am not sure I quite get your point. I know that the Weil formula can be used, but your method has left $f$ undefined; is there a formula that can be deduced by this method that is any simpler than the Guinand formula I quoted? I suspect that this is not the case.

Comment: @Anon The answers to a similar question at the following link provide more information on this topic: https://mathoverflow.net/q/82635

Comment: @StevenClark Thank you for the link; I'd actually already seen this question and linked to it in my question (the formula for $N^*(T)$ I gave is given in the answers to that question). What I was specifically looking for was a different way of counting $\rho$ that gave a more elegant and perhaps intuitive formula than the formula for $N^*(T)$ I've given (just as we can count the primes by $\psi^*(x)$ rather than by $\pi^*(x)$ and get a simpler explicit formula).